# want to pass JSON String to javascript variable [ JSON.parse(),eval()] are not working to me both returning unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, getjson

when i echo my php array it displays like this

echo json_encode($marray);

**DISPLAY**

{"marray":[{"lat":"12.34","long":"76.35"},{"lat":"13.60","long":"77.34"},{"lat":"14.45","long":"78.70"},{"lat":"12.12","long":"79.47"}]}

i checked my json_string(above) in online json formatter ...it displays no error in it.

i am using ajax to get the json string in this variable- xmlhttp.responseText ;

if i print that variable it displays the same ourput as it did in php echo statement;

but if i copy and paste the json string above directly(without using ajax response) into a javascript variable it displays

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

then i can use dot operator to fetch datas from it .....

i dont know whats the problem happening when json string stored into js variable as a response from a php file.

there are many threads regarding these but still i cant figure out my problem ....JSON.parse() nad eval() is not working to me.

MY php coding...

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$length=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$marray[$i] =

array(
"lat" => $row['lat'],
"long" => $row['long']
     );
$i++;
}
$dmarray=array("marray"=>$marray);
echo json_encode($dmarray);
```

**please help me ....the problem seems silly but it cost ,me 3 full day of sleepless nights**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function displayvalue()
{
m="xxx";
     var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
var h=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="h";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","array.php?q="+m,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code you're using to parse the JSON?

Comment: wait i will post it thanks for replying to my question Micheal

Comment: Michael Sandino i added the java script plz help me

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there. You're not using the response anywhere ..

Comment: i cant able to parse the json if i use JSON.parse(),eval()....

it displays error as unexpected token in json.parse

Comment: Would you post that code please?

Comment: document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="h";
it displays

{"marray":[{"lat":"12.34","long":"76.35"},{"lat":"13.60","long":"77.34"},{"lat":"14.45","long":"78.70"},{"lat":"12.12","long":"79.47"}]}

Comment: `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="h";` should be `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=h;`.

Comment: if i copy the following code directly into java script variable 
.................................................

{"marray":[{"lat":"12.34","long":"76.35"},{"lat":"13.60","long":"77.34"},{"lat":"14.45","long":"78.70"},{"lat":"12.12","long":"79.47"}]}

.......................

then it displays [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: sorry Barmer i mistyped it ... it is 
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=h;.

Comment: If you copy it into a Javascript variable without quoting it, then it gets parsed by the Javascript parser.

Comment: Please show how you're trying to use JSON.parse() in the code.

Comment: r u guys able to understand my problem sry my english is not that good 

....whats my problem is 

if the json encoded string is stored in a js variable as a response from ajax it displays the json as it echoed in php...

if i copy what it echoed in php diretly into java script variable i am getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].......whats going wrong PLZ help me

Comment: See http://www.json.org/js.html for a simple example of how to parse JSON.

Comment: i am using like this

var temp=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: if i use JSON.parse or eval() ...

my program stops in that position..if i seee the console it shows "unexpected token in json.parse in my JSON.js file

Comment: My only guess now is to check the raw output of the PHP-script and check that there are really no invalid chars in the response (might be unprintable ones).

Answer (score 0):

A simple (and working) testing example for your reference:

PHP:

```
<?php

$datastr = '{"marray":[{"lat":"12.34","long":"76.35"},{"lat":"13.60","long":"77.34"},{"lat":"14.45","long":"78.70"},{"lat":"12.12","long":"79.47"}]}';
$dataarray = json_decode($datastr);
die(json_encode($dataarray));

?>
```

JavaScript (html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function togetdata(callback) {
    var httpRequest;
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = getresponse;
        httpRequest.open('GET', "webpage.php");
    httpRequest.send();

    function getresponse() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                    callback(httpRequest.responseText);
                } else {
                    alert("Request Error");
                }
            } else {
        }
    }

}

function objstr(obj) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i in obj) {
        var v = obj[i];
        if (typeof v == "object") {
            v = objstr(v);
            s += i + ":<br>" + v + "<br>";
        } else {
            s += i + ": " + v + "<br>";
        }
    }
    return s;
}

function processdata(resp) {
    var r = JSON.parse(resp);
    var m = document.getElementById("msg");
    m.innerHTML = objstr(r);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="ajaxButton" onclick="togetdata(processdata)">To get data</button>

<span id="msg"></msg>
</body>
```

Comment: but i am getting unexpected token in JSON.parse in Json.js file

Comment: It seems you have ran into a strange bug. Maybe you should identify the bug first. You can start from a minimized working version (such as [my testing example](http://befree.likulaw.info/ajax_test/ajax.html)), and add more codes back step by step until the bug happens again.  I guess you may have include some old JavaScript libraries which affected JSON.parse.